# Character Jump Arc? Alter the Y axis during Vector3.MoveTowards?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a character jump between two points. The two points are varying distances apart, and at different heights.

I have the character moving from point to point using Vector3.MoveTowards in a IEnumerator. But how can I make modify the Y axis so that the character moves in a curved path to appear as if jumping?

The character needs to land exactly at each point, so I cannot use physics.

Thanks! :-)

[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psv0W.png)

Extra bonus points if you can adjust where you want the peak of the jump to occur (so the curve isn't perfectly circular, but more like an arc) E.g. so that the peak of the jump is closer to destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your given image, I would suggest using a projectile motion's equation to calculate the path between the source and destination in a given time with a given **start velocity(Vo)** and given **angle (theta)**.
In case you are not familiar with projectile equation, have a look at here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion 
In the **Displacement** section you'll find 2 equations like this:
x = Vo * T * cos(theta)
y = Vo * T * sin(theta) - 0.5 * g * pow(T,2)
So, in `Update` function don't move the object directly towards the target, rather take temporary targets along the projectile motion, which you can calculate using the above two equations. You can then use,

```
Vector3.MoveTowards(curPosition,new Vector3(x,y,0),step);
```

Considering, the `z` value is 0.

Comment: I was afraid it would be something to do with Sine/Cosine. I have some maths to learn :-)

Thank you!